# Manipulating XML in R unintendedly changes content of Tags

Tags: r, xml

My programme parses an XML-File with:

```
require(XML)

data <- xmlTreeParse("excel_output.xml")

xml_data <- xmlToList(data)
```

The XML-File looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Meldung  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Tarifmeldung.xsd">
    <somecontent></somecontent>
</Meldung>
```

Then I manipulate the content of the file. More specific I add a Base64-encoded file. In the last part of my programme I save the XML-File:

```
 data <- xmlRoot(data)
 saveXML(data, file = 'r_output.xml')
```

However, this process changes the second line of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Meldung noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Tarifmeldung.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <manipulated content> </manipulatedcontent
</Meldung>
```

By saving, the `xsi:` part of the "SchemaLocation" is dropped and the order of the to attributes is changed. When passing the File to a webservice this causes the service to reject my file.

Being an absolute beginner for XML-Files in R my question is: How can I prevent R from doing this an what am I doing wrong that this happens.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

To keep namespace information you can use argument `addAttributeNamespaces = TRUE` and to keep order of elements `useInternalNodes = TRUE` :

```r
require(XML)

xmldoc <-'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Meldung  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Tarifmeldung.xsd">
    <somecontent></somecontent>
</Meldung>'

data <- xmlTreeParse(xmldoc, addAttributeNamespaces = TRUE ,useInternalNodes = TRUE)
xml_data <- xmlToList(data)
data <- xmlRoot(data)

XML::saveXML(data)
#> [1] "<Meldung xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"Tarifmeldung.xsd\">\n  <somecontent/>\n</Meldung>"
```